# 'pod install' giving error on Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode7

I have updated my cocoapods(0.38.2) gem and xcodeproj(0.27.2), but still getting error:-

```
Writing Xcode project file to `Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
2015-09-24 09:40:27.969 ruby[12098:428715] [MT] DVTAssertions:      ASSERTION FAILURE in      /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-8227/IDEFoundation/Initialization/IDEInitialization.m:590
Details:  Assertion failed: _initializationCompletedSuccessfully
Function: BOOL IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction()
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb9adbd99d0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:0  0x000000011038ca5c -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x000000011038c1e9 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000011038c455 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000011038c3b7 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x00000001118c5f5c IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction (in IDEFoundation)
  5  0x000000011451deb9 +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x000000011451fa3e +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x00007fff8da7df44 ffi_call_unix64 (in libffi.dylib)
[1]    12098 abort      pod install --verbose
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `sudo xcode-select -r`

If it didn't help, let me know

it helped for me

```
'pod --version' returned 0.37.2 (even after updating cocoa pods to 0.38.2) it would update but still for some reason use 0.37.2 for all pod commands
So what I did: 
1) run 'pod --verbose' to locate the 0.37.2, delete it manually
2) run 'gem list --local | grep cocoapods' to find all cocoa pods installed on machine
2.1) 'gem uninstall' everything returned by step2 
2.2) run 'gem list --local | grep cocoapods' just to make sure everything is deleted
3) '[sudo] gem uninstall cocoapods'
4) '[sudo] gem install cocoapods'
```

Or try home-brew update if you installed pod via brew before

Comment: Already tried. Not working. This resets xcode-select, but my xcode-select is configured to correct path.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, it worked. I removed everything as you suggested and installed 0.38.2. But before also w=on 'pod install --verbose' I was getting version 0.38.2. Still didn't understand what was the problem,

Answer (score 5):

I just installed newer version, all error went away. sudo gem install cocoapods --pre. 
I had 0.37.2, i updated to a beta version 0.39.0

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to update your cocoapods gem using **sudo** ?

> sudo gem update

Answer (score 0):

**I got same error while pod installation.**

Following commands work for me.

```
~> sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
~> sudo gem install cocoapods
~> pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

A **previous install with home-brew was the problem**, that it always points to an old version. Thank's Zhanserik Kenes

```
brew uninstall cocoapods
```