# Cocoapods Install/Update Error - Assertion failed: _initializationCompletedSuccessfully

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using `CocoaPods` 0.39 and `XCode` 7.2, Initially I just setup project with following pods

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'CRToast'
pod 'SWRevealViewController'
```

Today, I'm added one more pod in my project pod file

```
pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
```

But every time either I'm trying to `pod update` or `pod install`, following error occurs

```
F0222:MyProject VCDev$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 1.0.0.beta.6 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (2.6.3)
Using CRToast (0.0.9)
Using Crashlytics (3.7.0)
Using Fabric (1.6.6)
Using SWRevealViewController (2.3.0)
Installing TPKeyboardAvoiding (1.2.11)
Generating Pods project
2016-03-16 11:23:15.680 ruby[2713:48496] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-9548/IDEFoundation/Initialization/IDEInitialization.m:590
Details:  Assertion failed: _initializationCompletedSuccessfully
Function: BOOL IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction()
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa103c98ff0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010d2c8f7f -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x000000010d2c870c _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010d2c8978 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010d2c88da _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010e7c354d IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction (in IDEFoundation)
  5  0x00000001113f8631 +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x00000001113fa1b6 +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x00007fff8667af44 ffi_call_unix64 (in libffi.dylib)
Abort trap: 6
```

I already tried following solution [given here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4209)

1. Update Cocoapods
2. Uninstall and Reinstall Cocoapods

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756433/pod-install-giving-error-on-xcode-7)?